# Outlook office-js how to forward selected email and add a recipient

Tags: outlook, office-js, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I am new to outlook office-js, and I am trying to get a selected email from a button click and forward the email. I am trying to find an example of how to get the selected email. I have done COM add-ins, and I guess I am looking for an explorer object. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For forwarding an item, you can use the `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId` API to get the item ID and using REST make an API call. There is a [concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api) page on calling REST APIs from an outlook add-in.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for!